# Angular needs a structure to follow?

Tags: angular

I am following the https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 tutorial to learn about angular. And apparently if the "Hero" class and "const HEROES" array are not above the "@Component" section, the application does not work. Any reason behind this? Is there a structure that needs to be followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is parsed top to bottom. So when the constant `HERORES` or the class `Hero` is referenced inside the component, they must already be known to the Javascript engine. Otherwise it does not recognize them and throws an error.

```
// ok
var name = 'Anna';
console.log(name);

// error: what's 'name'?
console.log(name);
var name = 'Anna'
```

it's not an Angular specific issue.

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank for that. But what is the point of making a "Hero" class or classes in general then. Do they have to be placed before the "AppComponent" class? Or is it just because of the const that has been created in this particular case only?

Comment: The point of classes is to make code scalable, so you don't have to re-write it every time you need to use the functionality that you put in that class. Look into introduction to Object Oriented Programming. As for your 2nd question, if the constant/class is in the same file it needs to be define before you can use it. Otherwise, if it's in another file, in needs to be imported at the top of your component file (the way you do `import {Component} from '@angular/core`

Comment: Thanks heaps. Sorts out the confusion to a fair amount. But about the "Hero" class, the code runs even if I place it after the "AppComponent" class, provided that there is no const.